# How to create a facebook login button in java swing?

Tags: java, facebook, swing

I am trying to create a facebook login button for a desktop application in java swing. What should I write in the Action event, so that when I click on the facebook login button, on a new window in the same application, the facebook login page opens for authenticating in the application?

Comment: Have you looked at the Facebook API?

Comment: Yes, but I am not able to use it in java swing.